# Show $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+\ln^{2}(2\cos(x))}dx=\frac{\pi}{8}\left(1-\gamma+\ln(2\pi)\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Here is an interesting, albeit tough, integral I ran across. It has an interesting solution which leads me to think it is doable. But, what would be a good strategy?.

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+\ln^{2}(2\cos(x))}dx=\frac{\pi}{8}\left(1-\gamma+\ln(2\pi)\right)$$

This looks rough. What would be a good start?.  I tried various subs in order to get it into some sort of shape to use series, LaPlace, something, but made no real progress.

I even tried writing a geometric series. But that didn't really result in anything encouraging.

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\left(\frac{\ln(2\cos(x))}{x}\right)^{2k}$$

Thanks all.

Comment: That geometric series does not converge over the whole of the range of integration, so it is not surprising that it didn't produce encouragement.
$$
\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\left(\frac{\log(2\cos(x))}{x}\right)^2=+\infty
$$

Comment: Yes, robjohn, that is obvious now. I was just grabbing at straws.  Perhpas digamma can be implemented in some fashion. That $\ln(2\pi)$ and $\gamma$ may suggest so. Just a thought.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this is closely related to the identity $$ \binom{\alpha}{\omega} := \frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\Gamma(1+\alpha-\omega)\Gamma(1+\omega)} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(1+e^{i\theta})^{\alpha}e^{-i\omega \theta}\;d\theta,$$ which holds for all $\alpha \geq 0$ and $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$, though I still cannot figure how it is related.

Comment: Apparently you're onto something, SOS.  This is mentioned in one of the papers Raymond posted links to.

Comment: $$I=\frac{\pi}{4} \left ( 1+ 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln x}{(x+1)(\pi^2+\ln^2x)}\text{d}x 
\right )$$Another:$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{x^2\ln(2\cos x)}
{\left ( x^2+\ln^2\left ( 2\cos x \right )  \right )^2 } \text{d}x
=\frac{7\pi}{192} -\frac{\pi}{96}\gamma+\frac{\pi}{8}\ln A$$

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In addition to the nice set of references by Raymond Manzoni, here is my proof of the identity. Frankly, I have not seen these references yet, thus I am not sure if this already appears in one of them.

Here I refer to the following identity

$$ \binom{\alpha}{\omega} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left(1 + e^{i\theta}\right)^{\alpha} e^{-i\omega \theta} \; d\theta, \ \cdots \ (1) $$

whose proof can be found in [my blog post](http://sos440.tistory.com/160).

Now let $x$ be a real number such that $|x| < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then simple calculation shows that

$$ \log\left(1+e^{2ix}\right) = \log(2\cos x) + ix \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad \Im \left( \frac{-x}{\log\left(1+e^{2ix}\right)} \right) = \frac{x^2}{x^2 + \log^2(2\cos x)},$$

hence we have

$$ \begin{align*}I
&:= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{x^2}{x^2 + \log^2(2\cos x)} \; dx
= -\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \Im \left( \frac{x}{\log\left(1+e^{2ix}\right)} \right) \; dx \\
&= -\frac{1}{8}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \Im \left( \frac{\theta}{\log\left(1+e^{i\theta}\right)} \right) \; d\theta
= \frac{1}{8}\Re \left(  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{i\theta}{\log\left(1+e^{i\theta}\right)} \; d\theta \right).
\end{align*}$$

Differentiating both sides of $(1)$ with respect to $\omega$ and plugging $\omega = 1$, we have

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (-i\theta) \left(1 + e^{i\theta}\right)^{\alpha} e^{-i\theta} \; d\theta = \alpha \left(\psi_0(\alpha) - \psi_0(2)\right). $$

Now integrating both sides with respect to $\alpha$ on $[0, 1]$,

$$ \begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{i\theta}{\log \left(1 + e^{i\theta}\right)} \; d\theta
&= \int_{0}^{1} \alpha \left(\psi_0(\alpha) - \psi_0(2)\right) \; d\alpha \\
&= \left[ \alpha \log \Gamma (\alpha) \right]_{0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1} \log \Gamma (\alpha) \; d\alpha - \frac{1}{2}\psi_0(2) \\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\left( 1 - \gamma + \log (2\pi) \right),
\end{align*}$$

where we have used the fact that

$$ \psi_0 (1+n) = -\gamma + H_n, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$

and

$$ \begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \log \Gamma (\alpha) \; d\alpha
& = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \log \left[ \Gamma (\alpha) \Gamma (1-\alpha) \right] \; d\alpha \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \log \left( \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi \alpha} \right) \; d\alpha \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left( \log \pi - \int_{0}^{1}  \log \sin \pi \alpha \; d\alpha \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \log (2\pi).
\end{align*} $$

Therefore we have the desired result.

Comment: Man, SOS, you're amazing!!!. :):)

Comment: SOS, may I ask, what are the 'simple calculations' that show the first line after the identity at (1)?.  I can't believe it, but I can actually follow the rest of it, I think. :)  Also when you differentiate, I assume it is w.r.t $\omega$?.

Comment: @Cody, the easiest way I think to prove this is to use the Euler's identity. Then $$ 1 + e^{2ix} = 2 \left( \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} \right) e^{ix} = 2 \cos x e^{ix}.$$ Or maybe you can prove it geometrically by considering the unit circle centered at $1$. Also, yes, the differentiation is taken w.r.t. $\omega$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. wonderful and ingenious proof

Comment: @Cody, Thanks for your praise! And I also found a critical typo and just fixed it right now.

Comment: Hi SOS.  I noticed that yesterday, but I did not want to bother you anymore. That's why I asked about the differentiation.

Comment: May I ask one more small thing, SOS, then I will leave you be.  I just like to follow everything that is going on.  How do we get from here  $log(2\cos(x))+ix$ to here $I\left(\frac{-x}{log(1+e^{2ix})}\right)$.  This is what I meant when I asked about it before.  Thanks for all of your input. It's been great.

Comment: @Cody, let $\log(1 + e^{2ix}) = \sigma + i\xi$. Then $$ \Im \left(\frac{-\xi}{\sigma+i\xi}\right)=\Im\left(\frac{(-\xi)(\sigma - i\xi)}{(\sigma + i\xi)(\sigma - i \xi)}\right)=\Im\left(\frac{(-\xi)(\sigma-i\xi)}{\sigma^2+\xi^2}\right) = \frac{\xi^2}{\sigma^2+\xi^2}.$$This procedure is quite standard.

Comment: Thanks, SOS.  This is why I like posting problems on this site. I always learn something new. Especially when those like you, robjohn, etc. have forgotten more than I'll ever know :)  Take care and thanks.

Comment: @sos440 sorry for me, what is the definition of the function $\psi_0$?

Comment: @vesszabo, it is the *[digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)*.

Answer (score 17):

To learn more about this very interesting integral I'll just provide the interesting links (the story itself is interesting since it was an experimental discovery first from Glasser and Oloa) :

- page 28 of Bailey & Borwein ['Computer-Assisted Discovery and Proof'](http://crd.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/dhbpapers/comp-disc-proof.pdf)
- Oloa's paper of 2007 'Some Euler-type integrals and a new rational series for Euler’s constant' at [google](http://books.google.com/books?id=ubqOl82xSG4C&pg=PA254) or [Les Mathématiques-net](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/file.php?4,file=6737,filename=EULER_TYPE_INTEGRALS_2007.pdf) (or in the link 'EULER_TYPE_INTEGRALS_2007.pdf' [here](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?4,367239,384434#msg-384434))
- Glasser & Mana ['The Laplace transform of the psi function'](http://docserver.carma.newcastle.edu.au/375/1/ContempMathFinal.pdf)
- Dixit 2009 ['The Laplace transform of the psi function'](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2010-138-02/S0002-9939-09-10157-0/S0002-9939-09-10157-0.pdf)
- Amdeberhan & Moll 2010 ['The Laplace transform of the digamma function: an integral due to Glasser, Manna and Oloa](http://arXiv.org/abs/0707.3663v1)
- Vildanov 2010 ['Generalization of the Glasser - Manna - Oloa integral and some new integrals of similar type'](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.3460)
- Coffey 2012 ['Certain logarithmic integrals, including solution of Monthly problem #tbd, zeta values, and expressions for the Stieltjes constants'](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.3393.pdf)
- Weisstein has [references](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DefiniteIntegral.html) too (see eq. (24))

  Fine reading !

Comment: Wow, I see now why I did not even know where to begin :)  Thanks for all of the articles, Raymond.

Comment: @Cody: Glad you found them interesting too! I discovered this 'mine' while searching 'log-sine' (log-cosine here) integrals.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni the paper Coffey 2012 has nothing to do with the integral in the title.

Comment: @Nemo: I don't remember the exact reason of this inclusion but $(1.10)$ for example contains $\int_0^1 \ln\Gamma(x)\, dx$ that matters in Sangchul Lee's answer. I notice too generalizations of $\int_0^1 t\psi(t) dt$ that could be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

We start by observing the following:
\begin{aligned}  
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)^s e^{iwx}\,dx&= \frac{1}{i} \oint \limits_{\gamma} \left(z+z^{-1}\right)^s z^{(w-1)}\,dz\\ 
&=  \frac{1}{i} \oint \limits_{\gamma} \left(z+z^{-1}\right)^s z^{(w-1)}\,dz\\ 
&=  \frac{1}{i} \oint\limits_{\gamma} \left(1+z^{2}\right)^s z^{(w-s-1)}\,dz  
\end{aligned}
where $\gamma$ a semicircle with in the upper positive halfplane with $\displaystyle{\substack{|z| = 1\\ -\pi/2 <\arg(z) < \pi/2}}$ recesses at the points $z = \pm i$. We complete the semicircle with a straight section that joins the points $z=-i$ and $z=i$ apart from the recesses $z=-i$,$0$, i. Then:
\begin{aligned}\oint\limits_{\gamma} \left(1+z^{2}\right)^s z^{(w-s-1)}\,dz &= e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(w-s)}\int_{0}^{1} (1-x^2)^sx^{w-s-1}\,dx+e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(w-s)}\int_0^{-1} (1-x^2)^sx^{w-s-1}\,dx\\ 
&= e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(w-s)}\int_{0}^{1} (1-x^2)^sx^{w-s-1}\,dx-e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}(w-s)}\int_0^{1} (1-x^2)^sx^{w-s-1}\,dx\\ 
&= 2i\sin \left(\frac{\pi (w-s)}{2}\right)\int_0^1 x^{w-s-1}(1-x^2)^s\,dx\\ 
&= i\sin \left(\frac{\pi (w-s)}{2}\right)B\left(\frac{w-s}{2},s+1\right)\end{aligned}
Consequently
$$\displaystyle{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)^s e^{iwx}\,dx = \sin \left(\frac{\pi (w-s)}{2}\right)B\left(\frac{w-s}{2},s+1\right)}$$
Producing as to w we have
\begin{aligned}&\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} x\left(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\right)^s e^{iwx}\,dx\\ 
&=-i\frac{d}{dw} \sin \left(\frac{\pi (w-s)}{2}\right)B\left(\frac{w-s}{2},s+1\right) \\&= -iB\left(\frac{w-s}{2},s+1\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(\frac{\pi (w-s)}{2}\right)\left(\psi\left(\frac{w-s}{2}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{w+s}{2}+1\right)\right) + \frac{\pi}{2}\cos \left(\frac{\pi (w-s)}{2}\right)\right)\end{aligned}
So for the original integral we have:
\begin{aligned}I&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x^2}{x^2+\log^2 (2\cos x)}\,dx \\&= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{x^2}{x^2+\log^2 (2\cos x)}\,dx\\ 
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathfrak{I}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\log (2\cos x) - ix}\,dx\\ 
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathfrak{I}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{x}{\log \left(1+e^{-2ix}\right)}\,dx\\ 
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathfrak{I}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^1 \frac{x(1+e^{-2ix})^s}{(1+e^{-2ix}) - 1}\,ds\,dx\\ 
&= \frac{1}{2}\mathfrak{I}\int_0^1\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} x(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})^se^{i(2-s)x}\,dx\,ds 
\end{aligned}
Setting w=2-s and using formulas $\displaystyle{B(1-s,1+s) = \frac{\pi s}{\sin \pi s}}$ and $\displaystyle{\psi(1-s) - \psi (s) = \pi\cot \pi s}$ the result is simplified in
\begin{aligned}I &= -\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1 s(\psi (1-s) - \psi (2) - \pi \cot \pi s)\,ds \\ 
&= -\frac{\pi}{4}\int_0^1 s(\psi (s) - \psi (2))\,ds\\ 
&= -\frac{\pi}{4}\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\gamma}{2} - \int_0^1 \log \Gamma(s)\,ds\right)\\ 
&= \frac{\pi}{8}\left(1-\gamma + \log (2\pi)\right) 
\end{aligned}