# Another two hard integrals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, integration, logarithms, definite-integrals

Evaluate :
$$\begin{align}
  & \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\frac{{{\ln }^{2}}\left( 2\cos x \right)}{{{\ln }^{2}}\left( 2\cos x \right)+{{x}^{2}}}}\text{d}x \\ 
 & \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\arctan \left( {{x}^{3+\sqrt{8}}} \right)}{1+{{x}^{2}}}}\text{d}x \\ 
\end{align}$$

Comment: For the second one, $x = \tan\theta$.

Comment: 0.683037, 0.0763652

Comment: For the first integral, refer to [my blog posting](http://sos440.tistory.com/348).

Comment: @sos440 : Thx sos440 :)

Comment: The first integral (subtracted from $\pi/2$) appeared before in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178790/show-int-0-frac-pi2-fracx2x2-ln22-cosxdx-frac-pi).

Comment: quick question: is $ln^2(f) = ln(ln(f))$ or $ln(f)^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the second integral, consider the more general form

$$\int_0^1 dx \: \frac{\arctan{x^{\alpha}}}{1+x^2}$$

(I do not understand what is special about $3+\sqrt{8}$.)

Taylor expand the denominator and get

$$\begin{align} &=\int_0^1 dx \: \arctan{x^{\alpha}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^{2 k} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \int_0^1 dx \: x^{2 k} \arctan{x^{\alpha}} \end{align}$$

Now we can simply evaluate these integrals in terms of polygamma functions:

$$\int_0^1 dx \: x^{2 k} \arctan{x^{\alpha}} = \frac{\psi\left(\frac{a+2 k+1}{4 a}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{3 a+2 k+1}{4 a}\right)+\pi }{8 k+4}$$

where

$$\psi(z) = \frac{d}{dz} \log{\Gamma{(z)}}$$

and we get that

$$\int_0^1 dx \: \frac{ \arctan{x^{\alpha}}}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{16} - \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\psi\left(\frac{3 \alpha+2 k+1}{4 \alpha}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{\alpha+2 k+1}{4 \alpha}\right) }{2 k+1} $$

This is about as close as I can get.  The sum agrees with the numerical integration out to 6 sig figs at about $10,000$ terms for $\alpha = 3+\sqrt{8}$.

Comment: Thx rlgordonma, I got about the same form of answer with another log integral..which I cant simplify too :)

Comment: See [here](http://link.zhihu.com/?target=https%3A//www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/acta-arithmetica/all/104/1/81999/a-restricted-epstein-zeta-function-and-the-evaluation-of-some-definite-integrals), the answer is $$\int_0^{1}\frac{\arctan x^{3+\sqrt{8}}}{1+x^2} = \frac{\ln 2 \ln(3+\sqrt{8})}{16}$$