# How is $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\psi(\alpha n)-\log(\alpha n)+\frac{1}{2\alpha n}\right)$ when $\alpha$ is great?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms, asymptotics, polygamma

Let $\psi := \Gamma'/\Gamma$ denote the digamma function.

Could you find, as $\alpha$ tends to $+\infty$, an equivalent term for the following series?

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \left( \psi (\alpha n) - \log (\alpha n) + \frac{1}{2\alpha n} \right)
> $$

Please I do have an answer, I'm curious about different approaches.

Thanks.

Comment: Related (for possible answerers): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872540/from-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-lefth-n-ln-n-gamma-frac12n-ri  I assume this is probably one of the things that prompted the OP's question.

Comment: Using the asymptotic series for digamma yields $\sim -\pi^2/(72a^2)$ immediately.

Comment: @Antonio Vargas Yes! $-\frac{\pi^{2}}{72}  \frac{1}{\alpha^{2}} + \frac{\pi^{4}}{10 \: 800}  \frac{1}{\alpha^{4}} +\, O\!\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^{6}}\right)$ Bernouilli numbers come ... Bravo!

Comment: It is interesting to notice that the first term of the asymptotics is just given by the inequality $\left(\frac{1}{\log z}+\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{z}{1-z}\leq\frac{\sqrt{z}}{12}$ when $z\in(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the Gauss formula:
$$-\psi(z)+\log(z) = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\log u}+\frac{1}{1-u}\right)u^{z-1}\,du$$
your series is just $-I(\alpha)$ due to the dominated convergence theorem, where:
$$ I(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{\log z}+\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{z^{\alpha-1}}{1-z^{\alpha}}\,dz.$$
Now, just like in [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874029/a-binet-like-integral-int-01-left-frac1-ln-x-frac11-x-frac), we have that:
$$ f(z) = \left(\frac{1}{\log z}+\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{z}{1-z} $$
is a positive, increasing and bounded function on $(0,1)$ that satisfies $f(z)\leq\frac{\sqrt{z}}{12}$. This gives that
$$ 0 \leq I(\alpha) \leq \frac{1}{6}-\frac{\pi}{12\alpha}\cot\frac{\pi}{2\alpha}=\frac{\pi^2}{72\alpha^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^4}\right), $$
hence the limit when $\alpha$ approaches $+\infty$ is simply zero.
Moreover, since we have $f(z)\geq\frac{z}{12}$,
$$ I(\alpha)\geq\frac{\alpha+\gamma+\psi(\alpha)}{12\alpha}=\frac{\pi^2}{72\alpha^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^3}\right),$$
hence:
$$ I(\alpha) = \frac{\pi^2}{72\alpha^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^3}\right).$$

Comment: Dear Jack, you have in fact proved that the series is $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^{2}}\right)$, could you please improve your formulae in order to get $\sim -\frac{\pi^{2}}{72}  \frac{1}{\alpha^{2}}$, so I could accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Ok, that was not so hard, just a consequence of $f(x)\geq x/12$, done.

Comment: It's OK for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With [Digamma Identity](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm) $\ds{\bf\mbox{6.3.21}}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\Psi\pars{\alpha n} - \ln\pars{\alpha n} + {1 \over 2\alpha n}}}
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{-2\int_{0}^{\infty}{t\,\dd t \over \pars{t^{2} + \alpha^{2}n^{2}}\pars{\expo{2\pi t} - 1}}}\tag{1}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{2 \over \alpha^{2}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{t\,\dd t \over \bracks{1 +t^{2}/\pars{\alpha^{2}n^{2}}}
\pars{\expo{2\pi t} - 1}}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{2 \over \alpha^{2}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{1 - {t^{2} \over \alpha^{2}n^{2}} + {t^{4}\over \alpha^{4}n^{4}} - \cdots}{t\,\dd t \over  \expo{2\pi t} - 1}
\\[3mm]&=\bracks{-2\,
\overbrace{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}}^{\ds{\pi^{2} \over 6}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{t\,\dd t \over \expo{2\pi t} - 1}}^{\ds{1 \over 24}}}\
\,{1 \over \alpha^{2}}
+\bracks{2\
\overbrace{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{4}}}^{\ds{\pi^{4} \over 90}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{3}\,\dd t \over \expo{2\pi t} - 1}}
^{\ds{1 \over 240}}}\,{1 \over \alpha^{4}}
\\[3mm]&\phantom{}+\bracks{-2\
\overbrace{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{6}}}^{\ds{\pi^{6} \over 945}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{5}\,\dd t \over \expo{2\pi t} - 1}}
^{\ds{1 \over  504}}}\,{1 \over \alpha^{6}} + \cdots
\\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large-\,{\ \pi^{2} \over 72}\,{1 \over \color{#c00000}{\alpha^{2}}} + {\ \pi^{4} \over 10800}\,{1 \over \color{#c00000}{\alpha^{4}}}
- {\ \pi^{6} \over 238140}\,{1 \over \color{#c00000}{\alpha^{6}}} + \cdots}
\end{align}

> Indeed, there is a closed expression, in terms of an integral, because the serie in $\pars{1}$ is given by:
>   $$
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over t^{2} + \alpha^{2}n^{2}}
> ={1 \over 2\alpha t^{2}}\,\bracks{\pi t\coth\pars{{\pi \over \alpha}\,t} - \alpha}
> $$

\begin{align}&\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\Psi\pars{\alpha n} - \ln\pars{\alpha n} + {1 \over 2\alpha n}}
=\int_{0}^{\infty}
{1 - \pars{\pi t/\alpha}\coth\pars{\pi t/\alpha} \over t}
\,{\dd t \over \expo{2\pi t} - 1}
\end{align}

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the $\pi^2$ term in the final line.

Comment: @Alyosha Fixed. I'm almost sleeping ( 3 a.m. right now ). Thanks.

Comment: @Felix Marin Thank you for this approach. (+1)

Comment: @OlivierOloa I add the closed expression you can check it. Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a comment including hyperlinks. @Felix Marin OK! Thanks! Your result with your integral is also a consequence of Ramanujan's result: Theorem 1 ([here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872540/from-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-lefth-n-ln-n-gamma-frac12n-ri))+ equation (22) ([here](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram14.pdf)) ($\alpha=e^n$).