# Asymptotic behavior of Harmonic-like series $\sum_{n=1}^{k} \psi(n) \psi'(n) - (\ln k)^2/2$ as $k \to \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, polygamma, stieltjes-constants

I would like to obtain a closed form for the following limit:
$$I_2=\lim_{k\to \infty} \left ( - (\ln k)^2/2 +\sum_{n=1}^{k} \psi(n) \, \psi'(n)  \right)$$

Here $\psi(n)$ is digamma function.

Using the method detailed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/874925/14825), 
I was able to compute simpler, related series:
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{k} \left (\psi'(n) -1/n \right) =1 $$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \psi''(n) =-\frac{\pi^2}{3} $$
But $I_2$ seems to be tougher because of the product of two digamma's.
The divergence of $(\ln k)^2$ is matched by the first terms of asymptotic series for $\psi(n) \psi'(n)$,  via the definition of the [Stieltjes number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants#Representations), $$ \lim_{k\to \infty} \left ( \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{\ln n}{n}  - (\ln k)^2/2 \right ) =\gamma_1 $$
but I am stuck with the reminder term.

**Side remark**: the problem originates in physics, see [my older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393334/fourier-transform-of-gamma-left-frac12-i-fracp2-pi-right-sqrt). In particular, I was able to show that $\langle x \rangle \approx -0.251022$ defined in that question actually equals exactly  $-(1+\gamma_0)/(2 \pi)$ where $\gamma_0$ is Euler's constant. This answer I seek here is the only piece missing on my path to closed form $\langle x^2 \rangle$.

Comment: this might be useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882621/polygamma-function-series-displaystyle-sum-k-1-infty-left-psi1k/883750#883750 nice question btw. (+1)

Comment: @tired thanks! Yes, already noticed from SE suggestions, spent a couple of hours with that. Summation has to go to finite $k$, otherwise the corresponding $(u,v)$ integral diverges (as the series diverge). Need to figure out how to deal with divergent terms in that approach...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**. One may obtain, for $N\ge1$,

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{n=1}^{N} \psi(n) \, \psi'(n)&=\left(N\psi(N)-N+\frac12\right)\psi'(N)+\frac{\psi(N)^2}2- \psi(N)+\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\gamma-\frac{\gamma^2}2  \tag1
> \end{align}
> $$

equivalently, for $N\ge1$,
$$
\small{\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=1}^{N} \left(H_{n-1}-\gamma\right)\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-H_{n-1,2}\right)
\\&=\left(NH_{N-1}-(\gamma+1)N+\frac12\right)\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}-H_{N-1,2}\right)+\frac{\left(H_{N-1}-\gamma\right)^2}2-\frac{H_{N-1,2}}2-H_{N-1}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\gamma^2}2, 
\end{align}}
$$ then, one may recall the standard [asymptotic expansions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11) of the polygamma functions $\psi=\Gamma'/\Gamma$ and $\psi'$,  as $X \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\psi(X)&= \ln X- \frac{1}{2X}-\frac{1}{12X^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{X^4}\right)
\\\psi'(X)&= \frac{1}{X}+\frac{1}{2 X^2}+\frac{1}{6 X^3}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{X^4}\right)
\end{align}
$$ yielding, as $N \to \infty$,

> $$
> -\frac{(\ln N)^2}2 +\sum_{n=1}^{N} \psi(n) \, \psi'(n)=\color{#9E15E3}{\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\gamma-\frac{\gamma^2}2-1}+\frac{\ln N}{12N^2}-\frac{1}{24N^2}+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\ln N}{N^4}\right) \tag2
> $$

then one gets the desired limit.

To prove $(1)$ one may use a [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Statement) with
$$
f_n=\psi(n),\quad g_{n+1}-g_n=\psi'(n),\quad g_1=\frac{\pi^2}6,\quad n\ge1.
$$
The above asymptotic expansion can be obtained at any order.

Comment: According to Wolfy, the value of the constant term is 0.921337593381... which agrees nicely with Claude Leibovici's computation.

Comment: Not surprizing at all, one more elegant answer ! Cheers.

Comment: What is surprizing is that ISC did not identify the number.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you. I've already noticed that ISC does not recognize some numbers involving some standard constants...

Comment: that easy...(+1)

Comment: Is it possible to find the limit for slightly general case, such as $$\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N} \Psi(na)\Psi'(na) - \frac{(\ln N)^{2}}{2}$$ for $a>0$? Maybe we have to multiple some constant to $(\ln N)^{2}/2$.

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer.*

Considering $$I_2(k)=\sum_{n=1}^k \psi ^{(0)}(n)\,\, \psi ^{(1)}(n)-\frac{\log ^2(k)}{2}$$ being stuck, I generated a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & I_2(k) \\
 1000 & -0.92133705940182217478 \\
 2000 & -0.92133744544582151652 \\
 3000 & -0.92133752387787776354 \\
 4000 & -0.92133755278727115778 \\
 5000 & -0.92133756665730197883 \\
 6000 & -0.92133757440092091621 \\
 7000 & -0.92133757917436506891 \\
 8000 & -0.92133758233024150188 \\
 9000 & -0.92133758452841907625 \\
 10000 & -0.92133758612266202362
\end{array}
\right)$$ The inverse symbolic calculators I used did not identify the result.

Comment: Very nice! Looks like at least $k^{-1}$ convergence, perhaps even $k^{-2}$. I played my CAS (Mathematica, NSum), reasonably confident in the following digits $I_2 = -0.921337593 \ldots$.

Comment: The values I gave are exact (I just printed 20 significant figures) but this took a lot of time. I am curious to see if a solution would come. Cheers.

Comment: Here is my code: i2=StieltjesGamma[1] + 
 NSum[PolyGamma[0, m] PolyGamma[1, m] - Log[m]/m, {m, 1, \[Infinity]},
   WorkingPrecision -> 120, PrecisionGoal -> 60, AccuracyGoal -> 60]. It converges very fast, and the digits do not change if I go to high accuracy/precision targets.

Comment: @Slaviks. Nothing came from this number. Sorry about it  http://www.mrob.com/pub/ries/index.html is what I used plus the advanced ISC you access from the same page.

Comment: Sorry to have erased the number accidentally. Here are presumably exact 120 digits: -0.9213375933812789795294925715398998032068005298260067547946440913103209312653457070731450224937203963739831413117519870420685374964590569966712976819292474819946352786054653773359444216685612588648538004563125850622758312738970151542730570

Comment: This agrees nicely with Olivier Oloa's result.